# goog.provide() - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, google-closure, limejs

So I decided today to play around with LimeJS a bit, I've never used Closure before so that is new to me as well. I've run into a small problem right off the bat and am not sure what is wrong.

So far my project is only three files: `firstGame.html`, `firstGame.js`, `player.js

firstGame.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <title>firstGame</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../closure/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="firstGame.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="player.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="firstGame.start()"></body>

</html>
```

firstGame.js:

```
goog.provide('firstGame');


//get requirements
goog.require('lime.Director');
goog.require('lime.Scene');
goog.require('lime.Layer');
goog.require('lime.Circle');
goog.require('lime.Label');
goog.require("lime.Sprite");
goog.require('lime.animation.Spawn');
goog.require('lime.animation.FadeTo');
goog.require('lime.animation.ScaleTo');
goog.require('lime.animation.MoveTo');
goog.require("firstGame.Player");


// entrypoint
firstGame.start = function(){

    var director = new lime.Director(document.body,1024,768);
    director.makeMobileWebAppCapable();
    scene = new lime.Scene();
    var background = new lime.Sprite().setSize(1524,768).setPosition(0,0).setFill(0,0,0).setAnchorPoint(0,0);
    var player = new firstGame.Player();
    scene.appendChild(background);
    // set current scene active
    director.replaceScene(scene);

}


//this is required for outside access after code is compiled in ADVANCED_COMPILATIONS mode
goog.exportSymbol('firstGame.start', firstGame.start);
```

and finally player.js(the idea was a custom ui component so I inherit from Sprite):

```
goog.provide("firstGame.Player');


goog.require('lime.Sprite');

// new constructor
firstGame.Player = function(){
    // call parents constructor
    goog.base(this);

    // custom initialization code
    this.color_ = 'red';
}
// define parent class
goog.inherits(firstGame.Player,lime.Sprite);
```

I then ran `lime.py update` (not sure if I needed to because I was only adding a class and not a whole new namespace but figured I should just to be safe)

When I load the page I get the unexpected token error noted above, this happens on line 1 of player.js, goog.provide(). Now if I remove player.js from the script path in my html file I find my other code runs ok which suggests that I am linking to the Closure library as expected. It's just when I try to use it in player.js that I run into the problem. My first inclination was that maybe the code was executing before the Closure library was parsed, I looked for some hook to tie into when Closure loaded but couldn't find anything. I've Googled around and haven't found an answer. I feel like I am missing something simple but can't quite get it. If anyone had any advice I would appreciate it, thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
goog.provide("firstGame.Player');
```

should be

```
goog.provide('firstGame.Player');
```

your qoutes don't match.

Comment: How did I not see that? Thank you!